# Can't push new updates to remote

Tags: git, github, push, github-actions, github-for-windows

I started this project on another PC and now I'm trying to continue it on my laptop. The issue is that while I added the GitHub remote repository URL to VB Code, when I press Push I receive

> "Git: fatal: No configured push destination"

and when I press Push to and select the remote (in format: https://github.com/username/projectname.git) it just loads forever.

I can't figure out what I'm missing so I can save the modifications to my remote. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Please open a terminal at the root of this Git repo, and run `git remote -v` to see what are the remotes you configured. Edit your question to include such key information, so that others might help you out.

Comment: with `git remote -v` the configured remote repos are listed. You might add with `git remote add <name> <url>` you can add additional or missing remotes. Default remote is typically named `origin`.